# Método Utilizando Array - Duvida

Tags: java

Boa noite,
Pessoal é possivel criar um método que setando apenas os atributos do produto já adicionem ele a lista no array? Se sim, poderiam me da uma dica?

Essa é só uma parte do código de uma Ordem de serviço de uma oficina (Trabalho da Facul).

```
insira o código aqui
    Produto[] caixa = new Produto[4];

    Produto p1 = new Produto();
    p1.setCodigo("0001");
    p1.setMarca("BMW");
    p1.setModelo("01");
    p1.setValor(220);
    p1.setProduto(TipoProduto.MOTOR);

    Produto p2 = new Produto();
    p2.setCodigo("003");
    p2.setMarca("HONDA");
    p2.setModelo("02");
    p2.setValor(300);
    p2.setProduto(TipoProduto.PNEUS);

    Produto p3 = new Produto();
    p3.setCodigo("0004");
    p3.setMarca("kAWASAKI");
    p3.setModelo("03");
    p3.setValor(1.500);
    p3.setProduto(TipoProduto.GUIDÃO);

    caixa[0] = p1;
    caixa[1] = p2;
    caixa[2] = p3;


    ordem.setListadeprodutos(caixa);

    for (int i = 0; i < caixa.length; i++) {

        System.out.println("Código :" + ordem.getListadeprodutos()[i].getCodigo());
        System.out.println("Marca :" + ordem.getListadeprodutos()[i].getMarca());
        System.out.println("Modelo :" + ordem.getListadeprodutos()[i].getModelo());
        System.out.println("Valor :" + ordem.getListadeprodutos()[i].getValor());

        System.out.println("\n");

    }
```

Comment: Boa noite!
Sim é possível! verifique o post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537980/equivalent-to-push-or-pop-for-arrays

Comment: Não entendi se você quer apenas descobrir o método que adiciona o produto à caixa , ou se quer criar um método que adicione os produtos à caixa passando como parametro os atributos de produto.

Comment: Eu tava na duvida se dava pra fazer, mais pelo q tô pesquisando é possível, séria criar um método que adicione 1 produto por vez a  caixa do array, passando como parâmetro os atributos do produto.

Comment: Nesse caso, você pode criar um construtor na classe Produto que já o instancie pelos seus atributos, isso iria economizar algumas linhas de código, crie também um array com escopo global e em seguida um método que instancie um novo produto e o jogue na próxima posição vazia do array. vai evitar tanta duplicidade no seu código.

Comment: Valeu, só tava faltando uma direção de como fazer, vou tentar.